# Small orbital body detection

Tags: orbit

What technology is required to detect a coconut-sized sphere in Earth orbit, at average altitude of communications satellites?

Comment: I don't know too much about this, but try to look up "space debris detection" and go from there

Comment: are you suggesting the [coconut got there carried by swallows](https://youtu.be/liIlW-ovx0Y?t=44)?

Comment: Good question but I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here because it's not about Astronomy as defined in the [help center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is however *on-topic* in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) and should be asked there instead.

Comment: @uhoh,  ya ninja'd me there.  But seeing as the OP said "coconut-sized," guess it'd have to get there via a swallow-sized rocket.